# Parsing datestring into timestamp correctly?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script

[image]

I'm working with apps script.

I'm parsing sheet rows into objects and I'm trying to filter them by time to get the the most recent entries in the last hour

```
[{relativeRow=257.0, ME=, Index=false, FROM=1.xxx, absoluteRow=258.0, Timestamp=Fri Sep 20 14:17:50 GMT-04:00 2019, CONVERSATION=R:Yes!}, {relativeRow=256.0, ME=, Index=false, FROM=1xxx, absoluteRow=257.0, Timestamp=Fri Sep 20 12:18:00 GMT-04:00 2019, CONVERSATION=R:yes yes}, {relativeRow=255.0, ME=, Index=false, FROM=xxx, absoluteRow=256.0, Timestamp=Thu Sep 19 11:54:29 GMT-04:00 2019, CONVERSATION=R:Yes1}]
```

I have:

```
var MILLIS_PER_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;  // 60 MINUTES
var now = new Date()
var oneHouragoTS = now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_HOUR;
  Logger.log(oneHouragoTS);

var pendingRows =  descending.filter(function (row) {

    Logger.log(row['Timestamp']);

var rowDate = new Date(row['Timestamp'])
var rowTS = rowDate.getTime()

Logger.log('rowTS');
Logger.log(rowTS);
    Logger.log('oneHouragoTS');
Logger.log(oneHouragoTS);



var diff = rowTS - oneHouragoTS ;


Logger.log('diff');
Logger.log(diff);

return (diff>0) 

});
```

The output:

```
[19-09-20 15:40:54:016 EDT] getResponsesOverLastHour
[19-09-20 15:40:54:017 EDT] 1.569004854016E12
[19-09-20 15:40:54:017 EDT] Fri Sep 20 14:17:50 GMT-04:00 2019
[19-09-20 15:40:54:018 EDT] rowTS
[19-09-20 15:40:54:018 EDT] 1.56900347E12
[19-09-20 15:40:54:019 EDT] oneHouragoTS
[19-09-20 15:40:54:019 EDT] 1.569004854016E12
[19-09-20 15:40:54:020 EDT] diff
[19-09-20 15:40:54:020 EDT] -1384016.0
[19-09-20 15:40:54:020 EDT] Fri Sep 20 12:18:00 GMT-04:00 2019
[19-09-20 15:40:54:021 EDT] rowTS
[19-09-20 15:40:54:021 EDT] 1.56899628E12
```

I'm running this 30-40 minutes after the row was created, so I would assume that the diff would be positive and the row returned , however the diff is negative and filtering for rows created within 1 hour returns an empty array

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your oneHourAgo is `Fri Sep 20 2019 14:40:54 GMT-04:00` and your rowDate is `Fri Sep 20 2019 14:17:50 GMT-0400`, and you are subtracting oneHourAgo (which is larger) from rowDate, so you get a negative value. In other words, the value in the table is more than one hour old.

Comment: but if I'm running this half an hour after the row (and timestamp) is created, shouldn't rowTS be greater than oneHouragoTS ?

Comment: See my answer. You are not running it 30-40 minutes later. You are running it 1 hour and 30-40 minutes later.

Comment: The time in the record is 14:17. 30 minutes later is 14:47, but you are running it at 15:40. 14:17 is more than one hour before 15:40.

Comment: I was running it manually 30-40 minutes later , so now I'm wondering if there is a time zone problem..

Comment: Well, the timestamp in your log says you run it 15:40, and the time in the sheet is 14:17. So either a clock is wrong somewhere, or your are wrong, or some alien abducted you...

Comment: Your log entry is in Eastern Daylight Time (EDT) (GMT-04:00), and your timestamps are also displayed in GMT-04:00.

Comment: I checked the original function where I create the row and I'm using "  var date =Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "EST", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
" Maybe I should cjange it to "GMT"

Comment: If the library supports UTC I would recommend that. (UTC has been the official time since 1972, so they have had 47 years to implement it in the library). If UTC isn't available you can use GMT since it probably is handled as it was UTC. It almost always is easier to store the timestamp in UTC, and only convert it to another time zone when displaying it to the user. That minimizes problems with time zones and daylight savings.

Comment: thanks, I'm just glad it wan't an alien abduction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date in your sheet is Fri Sep 20 14:17:50 GMT-04:00 2019

It can be parsed by the `new Date("Fri Sep 20 14:17:50 GMT-04:00 2019")`

```js
console.log(new Date("Fri Sep 20 14:17:50 GMT-04:00 2019"))
```

Your calculation of one hour ago, is also correct:

```js
var oneHourAgo = Date.now() - (60*60*1000); // shorter version

console.log(oneHourAgo, new Date(oneHourAgo));
```

But, you are not running it 30-40 minutes after it was created. **You are running it 1 hour and 24 minutes later**: 19-09-20 15:40:54:016 EDT.

Therefore you get negative values, since they are older than one hour.

May I suggest an optimization of your filter?

```
var now = Date.now();

var pendingRows =  descending.filter(function (row) {
  var rowTS = Date.parse(row['Timestamp']);
  var diff = now - rowTS;
  Logger.log(row['Timestamp'], rowTS, diff);
  return diff < (60*60*1000); 
});
```